# How to use AWS S3 server side encryption SSE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Say for example I leave an AWS S3 bucket open to the public.

My goal is that if someone downloads a file from that bucket then what they get is an encrypted file.

I thought SSE-S3 would do this but it does not - it appears that any file downloaded is not encrypted.

So how can I reach my goal of ensuring that files served from S3 are encrypted?

Comment: Files served from S3 that were stored with SSE-SE and downloaded with HTTPS *are encrypted* while stored on hard drives at S3 and while being transferred across the Internet to the client, the two most relevant places for encryption.  If you want the client to actually receive a still-encrypted file... then you typically just upload an encrypted file to S3.  What is the use case for the file still being encrypted when the client receives it?  What do they do with it after that?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Protecting Data Using Client-Side Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html). If you want S3 to serve encrypted files, then you have to save them as encrypted object. You manage encryption/decryption. SSE will store the data after encrypting it and will decrypt it automatically when it is downloaded.

From: [Protecting Data Using Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html)

- **Use Server-Side Encryption** – You request Amazon S3 to encrypt your object before saving it on disks in its data centers and decrypt it when you download the objects.
- **Use Client-Side Encryption** – You can encrypt data client-side and upload the encrypted data to Amazon S3. In this case, you manage the encryption process, the encryption keys, and related tools.